# Не работает тактовый генератор на Миландр

Tags: микроконтроллеры, arm, миландр

Имеется микроконтроллер Миландр 1986ВЕ9. На нём не работает блок управления тактовым сигналом (и, как следствие, вся периферия). Любая запись в регистры MDR_RST_CLK не приводит ни к какому результату, в них как были нули, так нули и остались. Регистр MDR_RST_CLK->CLOCK_STATUS также обнулён. И даже MDR_BKP->REG_0F нулевой, то есть HSI не запущен. Как он вообще тогда работает? Но ядро работает. Как это лечить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл причину. Если программа записывает в регистр MDR_RST_CLK->PER_CLOCK значение 0, то она отключает всю периферию, включая сам тактовый генератор. После этого невозможно записать в этот регистр никакое значение. Программный (в том числе отладочный) reset ни к чему не приводит. После отключения-включения питания в этом регистре поднимается бит RST_CLK, то есть тактовый генератор снова работает. Контроллер начинает выполнять программу из flash-памяти, и обнуляет этот регистр, контроллер снова умирает. Из этого следует решение - нужно исключить исполнение программы из flash-памяти. Для этого следует воспользоваться управлением режимом загрузки и активировать, например, режим 010 (загрузка из внешней памяти и активация отладочного интерфейса B). После этого надо стереть память контроллера и вернуть прежний режим загрузки.